# Script email from specific email address

Tags: php, email, subdomain

I need a script that send a email from a specific email of my domain.

For example: if domain is www.mydomain.com, the script should send an email from info@mydomain.com (not from the server with anonymous email)

I've tried to use PHP function to send email:

```
<?

mail("to@server.com","Hello","Text","from@mydomain.com");

?>
```

But this method add at the beginnig of the mail the header with the sender's email and it does not send from the email that I have chosen.

Comment: google for `sendmail`with the `-f` flag, then pass the apropriate flag(s) via `mail()`

Comment: Your 4. parameter is wrong.
But don't forget that you have to configure your domain and server correctly or your emails would go instantly into the spam folder!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot "from:"

This should work:

```
mail("to@server.com","Hello","Text","from:from@mydomain.com");
```

Comment: You're right! I had just forgotten the 'from'! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = 'From: from@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: from@mydomain.com';

mail("to@server.com","Hello","Text", $headers);
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

The mail sent using mail() function is not secure and goes in the spam folder.In order to send email more securely try using PHPMailer. [click-here](https://github.com/PHPMailer)

Comment: No, it depends on the server config!

Comment: @Gerifield, yes but is it safe to use mail() to send mails in PHP?

Comment: yeah, why not? In the background that's the sendmail command.